# Is this function $f$ defined uniquely?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Consider function $f: \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$. ($0 \in \mathbb{N}$.) We know that:

- $f$ is bijective
- $f((0,1)) = (1,0)$
- $\forall x \forall y: x \leq y \implies f(x) \leq f(y)$ where $x \leq y \iff \exists z: x+z=y$

I would say that it indeed is enough and $f$ looks like this: $f((a,b)) = (b,a)$. Is there a way to prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

A formal proof would use induction over first $x_1+x_2$, for example. But to have an overview, note that we can define the notion of immediate predecessor of $(a,b)$ as an element $(x,y)$ such that $(x,y)< (a,b)$ and there is no $(u,v)$ with $(x,y)<(u,v)<(a,b)$ (and as this is defined only in terms of $\le $, the function $f$ must respect it). So the immediate predecessors of $(a,b)$ are apparently $(a-1,b)$ and $(a,b-1)$, provided they belong to the set; we conclude that $f((a,b))$ must have $f((a-1,b))$ and $f((a,b-1))$ as immediate predecessors, accordingly.

Comment: Wouldn't surjection be enough then?